# Pandas: Add row depending on index

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to create a dataFrame that is updated with itself(df3), adding rows from other dataFrames (df1,df2) based on an index ("ID").

When adding a new dataFrame if an overlap index is found, update the data. If it is not found, add the data including the new index.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Proj. Num" :["A"],'ID':[000],'DATA':["NO_DATA"]})
df1 = df1.set_index(["ID"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Proj. Num" :["B"],'ID':[100],'DATA':["OK"], }) 
df2 = df2.set_index(["ID"])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Proj. Num" :["B"],'ID':[100],'DATA':["NO_OK"], }) 
df3 = df3.set_index(["ID"])

#df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2, df3]) #Concat,merge,join???
df3
```

I have tried concatenate with _verify_integrity=False_ but it just gives an error, and I think there is a more simple/nicer way to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df3 = df3[~df3.index.duplicated()]
print (df3)
        DATA Proj. Num
ID                    
0    NO_DATA         A
100       OK         B
```

Another solution by [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024388/pandas-add-row-depending-on-index/44024484?noredirect=1#comment75081314_44024484), thank you:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df3,df1]) 
df3 = df3[~df3.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df3)
        DATA Proj. Num
ID                    
100    NO_OK         B
0    NO_DATA         A
```

Comment: The first solution does not work as I need to get the previous status of df3 and then append|update the df3&df4 DataFrames depending if the indes is already on df3.

The second solution does work but changing  **keep='first'**.
If you correct your answer this is a good solution.

Comment: Sorry, now solution is correct. `keep='first'` is by default, so can be omit.

Comment: Thank you. Actually you can post both solutions, if you keep the one you have now the values will be appended in the first row. Instead if you use **df3 = pd.concat([df3,df1])** and **df3 =df3[~df3.index.duplicated(keep='last')]** It will work and the values will be appended to the end instead. 

*I dropped the df2 as regarded redundant.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `2` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate all the dataframes along the index; [group by](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) index and decide which element to keep of the group sharing the same index.

From your question it looks like you want to keep the last (most updated) element with the same index. It is then important the order in which you pass the dataframes in the `pd.concat` function.
For a list of other methods, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes).

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 0)
res.groupby(res.index).last()
```

Which gives:

```
        DATA Proj. Num
ID                    
0    NO_DATA         A
100    NO_OK         B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#update existing rows 
df3.update(df1)
#append new rows
df3 = pd.concat([df3,df1[~df1.index.isin(df3.index)]])

#update existing rows 
df3.update(df2)
#append new rows
df3 = pd.concat([df3,df2[~df2.index.isin(df3.index)]])

Out[2438]: 
        DATA Proj. Num
ID                    
100       OK         B
0    NO_DATA         A
```